# Task Executor thread is not returned to pool in case of exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, threadpoolexecutor

when a nested chain fails and reaches the error channel flow, the task executor threads block and are not returned to pool. Is there any way to indicate that the end of flow has reached and they need to be returned to pool.

for example the splitter breaks the payload to 3 messages. The messages are served as -

```
message 1 - fileChannelTaskExecutor1
message 2 - fileChannelTaskExecutor2
```

if "nested-chain" gateway call is successful, the 3rd message is served to any of these executor thread which gets freed up earlier.

However if the "nested-chain" gateway call fails and reaches errChannel, both the above executor thread block and are not returned to pool. As a result of which successive messages(message 3) are not processed as no thread is available in pool.

```
<bean id="fileChannelTaskExecutor"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="daemon" value="false"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="splitterResponseChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="fileChannelTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:splitter input-channel="splitterRequestChannel" output-channel="splitterResponseChannel" >

<int:chain input-channel="splitterResponseChannel">
    <int:gateway request-channel="nested-chain" error-channel="errChannel"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="errChannel" output-channel="nullChannel">
     .....
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is around one-way `nullChannel` and the `<int:gateway>` request/reply nature.

Even if you send Exception to the `error-channel` you should should re-throw it to the call or return some `compensation` message from the error flow.
Other wise you end up with the hanging on the gateway which waits for the reply forever. By default, of course!

You can adjust `reply-timeout` on the matter and release your Thread to the pool over some time in case of that one-way error process.

Comment: In other words, if your error flow returns no reply to the gateway, the thread will wait there forever for a reply that will never come; setting the `reply-timeout="0"` will free up the thread. As long as you use only direct channels downstream of the gateway, a timeout of 0 will not hurt - the timer is not started until the thread returns to the gateway.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I have returned a compensation message from the error flow and merged the success and error flows thereafter. This solution was woderfull, it actually released the threads.

Comment: Gary, I had also tried setting the reply-timeout, but was not freeing up the threads. The process ends at nullChannel, as the flow does not return from error channel, reply-timeout wont have any effect. Am I missing something?